# How could I install the documentation of ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar libary on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

I downloaded the ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar library from code.google.com and attach it to my android project , but now I want to see the documentation of classes , how could I do that? 
please help me

Comment: do you got answer for this

Answer (score 0):

you can get your Problem Resolve from [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse)

also  from [Documentaion of ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/NeedHelp)

Hope it will Helps you.